# ExpressJS upload many files without EMFILE error

Tags: node.js, express

I need to handle a multiple file upload with ExpressJS where I dont't know the number of files uploaded by the client.

When I try to upload more than 244 files the server crash. The error is thrown during the upload between the upload form and the uploadHandle action. (the files are not all copied to my /public/upload folder, only the 244 first)

Increase the **ulimit** limitation seems to be a bit dirty because even if I set it to 10000, my server will crash if someone try to upload more files.

Is there a clean way to handle that ?

Thank you.

Comment: isaacs loves you https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not creating that many files at once feels like the correct approach.  You could handle this several ways, such as queueing them in the browser using the [HTML5 File Api](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) if you don't have to support legacy browsers.

You could also stream the files on the server side as they are received so that you aren't creating open file pointers, and buffering them to memory.  If you need to open all of those files and process them somehow, then as suggested, [node-graceful-fs](https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs) could help in that area.

Comment: I'm trying to handle it server-side, but the way Express handle the request don't let me implement what I want. I tried using [node-multiparty](https://github.com/superjoe30/node-multiparty) but as soon as I try to parse file the server crash. Am I missing something ?

Comment: By default, the body parser in express is going to parse the entire body, which isn't what you want, since it's too much to throw into memory and buffer at once.  Take a look at node-multiparty, and this example: https://github.com/superjoe30/node-multiparty/blob/master/examples/s3.js.  He's streaming incoming file uploads to amazon s3, but you could also stream them to the file system, and control how many are streaming at a time with an asynchronous queue, such as [async.queue()](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue)

Comment: I tried to use async.queue but I think the problem is in the way multiparty handle the file upload, I have opened an issue for that.